# run lambda in each of the s3 object in a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to build a system which will run a lambda function exactly once on each of S3 object once per year. assuming that there are millions of object in the bucket so the lambda function will be running a fixed numbers of times daily but it will be able to distinguish which objects have been processed and which ones haven't. I am having trouble with how to build that logic. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what's the best approach for this? any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe the problem more but not in terms of a solution?  It sounds like you'll need a backing store (DynamoDB, RDS, etc.) to keep track of what has and hasn't been processed but, again, we need a bit more information.

Comment: How intensive is the processing for each object (and how long does it take)? How large is each S3 object? Are you using the objects for anything else, or would you be open to keeping them somewhere else (eg in a database)? What do you mean by "once per year" -- must it be done on a specific date, exactly 365 days later, or can it be done earlier/later? If you provide more details of your actual situation, we are more likely to provide you with an appropriate answer. You can Edit your question anytime to add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea: maintain a list of the S3 objects in an RDBMS (or DynamoDB) where each record has the S3 key plus a next-process-date. Schedule a Lambda function once per day to query the DB for objects scheduled to be processed today (or earlier). Given that you have millions of objects, that's upwards of 3000 objects per day on average, so you may not be able to process them all within a single Lambda timeout so you could fan out the objects to be processed to more Lambda functions that you invoke with a subset of the objects to process (or even one object per Lambda). After a Lambda has processed an object, the Lambda would re-write the relevant record in the DB to indicate that the next-process-date was today plus one year.

To maintain the list of S3 objects in the DB, you could also use Lambda functions reacting to S3 objects being uploaded or deleted.